# how to render to blade the image stored in storage/app/public directory of Laravel 7.14?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am stuck. how to display the image stored in /storage/app/public directory of laravel 7.14 ?
I already tried the ones I found in stack overflow, or even the ones i found by googling.

I tried this solution

```
//Controller function
 public function renderPic($filename) {
      
      $path = '/storage/app/public/uploads/'.$filename;

      if (!File::exists($path)) {
           abort(404);
      }

      $file = File::get($path);
      $type = File::mimeType($path);

      $response = Response::make($file,200);
      $response->header("Content-Type",$type);
      return $response;
 }
```

web route

```
Route::get('user/renderPic/{filename}', 'User@renderPic')->name('user.renderPic');
```

blade view file

```
<img id="displayPic" src="{{ route('user.renderPic',$user->filename) }}">
```

it doesn't show up

Comment: Why are you rendering directly from the storage folder?

Comment: that is why am asking , I don't know how to display the image coming from the storage

Comment: I don't think you can display directly from storage because of the directory permissions, you should create a symlink.

Comment: can you please at least show how to do such thing, instead of just commenting out like that? thanks

Comment: Ok i will write an answer to explain it as best as i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a route and controller method to render an image.

you simply open a terminal in the root directory for your laravel app and run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this will make a symlink for the storage/app/public directory to public/storage

the in your blade file you simply render the image like so:

```
<img id="displayPic" src="{{ asset('storage/your-image-name.ext') }}">
```

Comment: does that mean, no need to indicate the "app" and  "public" directory ?..because it's storage/app/public/uploads

Comment: No you don't need to include /app/public
the `php artisan storage:link` command makes a symlink to the storage/app/public directory to /public/storage directory

Comment: you can check the generated symlink by opening the public folder and you should find a new shortcut/symlink directory called storage there

Comment: so if my image is stored in this real directory like this storage/app/public/uploads/myImage.jpg   .... it should be like this  is it ? asset('storage/uploads/myImage.jpg') ?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work :(   `src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/'.$user->filename) }}"`

Comment: Well that's odd, it should work
can you open your public folder and check the content of the storage directory see if the image actually exist in '/public/storage/uploads'
also what does `$user->filename` returns ? are you sure it only return the image name with the extension ?

Comment: that is strange.... inside storage/app/public/uploads/  the file does exist..but when i checked public/storage  ...nothing ,,what should I do ? , should I upload the photo inside the public/storage now, and not inside the storage/app/public/uploads ?

Comment: you don't have an uploads folder inside /app/storage ?
try deleting the /public/storage symlink and run 
`php artisan storage:link` command again

Comment: there are two different directories that I am seeing inside the laravel  1) storage/app/public/uploads    2) public/storage     ....my image is in the first one

Comment: Ok try deleting the second one and run the `php artisan storage:link` again.
maybe the first time there was an error or something

Comment: daemn...that has fixed the problem...As-salamu alaykum

Comment: Great, w alaykom al salam :)